# @opentelemetry/sdk-node vs @opentelemetry/sdk-tracing-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, open-telemetry

I am trying to play with open telemetry in a Node application. I find it a bit confusing that some examples ask me to install the `@opentelemetry/sdk-node` (like this [official guide](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/nodejs/)), while some others ask me to install `@opentelemetry/sdk-tracing-node` (like this one, also [offical guide](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/instrumentation/)).

The examples that require `@opentelemetry/sdk-node` have code like this:

```
const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new opentelemetry.tracing.ConsoleSpanExporter(),
  instrumentations: [
    // instrumentations...
  ]
});

sdk.start()
```

The ones using `@opentelemetry/sdk-tracing-node` are like this:

```
registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [
    // instrumentations...
  ]
});

const provider = new NodeTracerProvider();
const exporter = new ConsoleSpanExporter();
const processor = new BatchSpanProcessor(exporter);
provider.addSpanProcessor(processor);

provider.register();
```

They are somewhat similar, and I guess they achieve the same thing in the end. The questions are:

- what's the difference between these two approaches?
- is one of them better, maybe more recommended nowadays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sdk-node` also brings the metrics and logs SDK while `sdk-tracing-node` only brings tracing SDK.

If you only care about tracing for now and want to avoid pulling useless dependencies, you can use `sdk-tracing-node`.